# Repository.SaveOrUpdate(), certainty of rollback executed on exception?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, repository, rollback

For saving a list of (virtual) bank account transactions, I want the business entity to reflect the state saved to database, also in case of an exception.

Can I assume that an exception here also means the transaction is rolled back? Or can I explicitly rollback in the catch to be sure? If so, what if that line throws an exception?

In Repository< T >:

```
public void SaveOrUpdate(IList<T> entityList)
{
    using (ISession session = FluentNHibernateManager.OpenSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try 
            {
               foreach (T entity in entityList)
                  session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
               transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               MyTrace.Exception(e.ToString());
               // add this line?  transaction.Rollback();
               throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Some Class:

```
cashTransactions.Add(t);
try {
    GenericRepository<CashTransaction> repo = new GenericRepository<CashTransaction>();
    repo.SaveOrUpdate(cashTransactions);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    cashTransactions.Remove(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assume that the transaction was rolled back, but you don't have to assume: `ITransaction` has a `bool WasCommitted` property.

You can check that to determine whether the transaction was committed, and call `Rollback()` explicitly, where warranted.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta include the rollback() call to rollback the transaction properly.

Answer (score 0):

To dispose a not-commited transaction will always rollback it.
This is true in all ado.net transactions implementation, and of course at runtime NHibernate  will use your chosen ado.net provider.